# rpy2 installation error (OS: linux mint 17 | R 3.1.2 | python 2.7.6)

Tags: rpy2

When I run 'sudo pip install rpy2' I get the a lot of compilation errors.

[Here is the full dump of all the errors](http://www.pastebin.ca/2878069) and here is an example except:

```
 Compilation parameters for rpy2's C components:
        include_dirs    = ['/usr/share/R/include']
        library_dirs    = ['/usr/lib/R/lib']
        libraries       = ['R', 'pcre', 'lzma', 'bz2', 'z', 'rt', 'dl', 'm']
        extra_link_args = ['-Wl,--export-dynamic', '-fopenmp']

R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31) -- "Pumpkin Helmet"
building 'rpy2.rinterface._rinterface' extension
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DR_INTERFACE_PTRS=1 -DHAVE_POSIX_SIGJMP=1 -DRIF_HAS_RSIGHAND=1 -DCSTACK_DEFNS=1 -DHAS_READLINE=1 -I./rpy/rinterface -I/usr/share/R/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.o
In file included from /usr/share/R/include/R.h:46:0,
                 from ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.h:8,
                 from ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:58:
/usr/share/R/include/R_ext/Memory.h:40:1: warning: function declaration isn’t a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
 int R_gc_running();
 ^
In file included from ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.h:9:0,
                 from ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:58:
/usr/share/R/include/Rinternals.h:831:1: warning: function declaration isn’t a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
 const char *R_curErrorBuf();
 ^
In file included from ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:70:0:
/usr/share/R/include/Rinterface.h:129:1: warning: function declaration isn’t a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
 extern void (*ptr_R_ProcessEvents)();
 ^
In file included from ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:79:0:
/usr/share/R/include/R_ext/Rdynload.h:32:1: warning: function declaration isn’t a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
 typedef void * (*DL_FUNC)();
 ^
./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:86:31: fatal error: readline/readline.h: No such file or directory
 #include <readline/readline.h>
                               ^
compilation terminated.
```

Some background. Previously botched the installation of ipython notebook dev version and have reverted back to the pip repository version. Not sure if that plays a role. Was able to get R magic working a little before that.

I had made sure to run 'apt-get updates', 'pip uninstall rpy2', 'apt-get purge python-rpy2 && apt-get remove python-rpy2' before attempt to re-install. To check if there was any residual files, I ran 'import rpy2' in ipython and that resulted in an module not found error (good, nothing was lingering).

Not sure where to begin troubleshooting. Advice is appreciated.

---

Edit: Nov 26, 2014

It worked after installing the following dependencies:

- apt-get install libreadline-dev
- apt-get install r-base r-base-dev python-dev python-setuptools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the headers for the readline library:

```
apt-get install libreadline-dev
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I just tried installing libreaderline-dev on another PC with the same OS, packages and problem. The readline library was up-to-date but rpy2 still failed to compile with what looks to be the same errors. Will try installing the library on the original PC tomorrow. [dump of terminal output here](http://pastebin.com/rtSWztMw)

Comment: [Here is the dump with the original PC](http://www.pastebin.ca/2878561) - running the command did update it, but still ran into compile error.

Comment: Well, that's a different error message after adding libreadline-dev then (and adding libreadline-dev did solve the original issue). Then what you had missing is lzma (which should have been pulled with the .deb for R - may be something rather unusual with your last cal install or the Linux Mint packages.)

Comment: Ya. The problem must have been missing dependencies which was resolved by updating R. A separate issue: when I try %load_ext rpy2.ipython , I get an import error: 'no module named singledispatch'. Do you know if that command is correct?