# %load_ext rpy2.ipython doesn't work - module not found (OS: linux mint 17 | R 3.1.2 | python 2.7.6 | ipython notebook 2.3.1 | rpy2 2.5.2)

Tags: jupyter-notebook, rpy2

Having problems getting %R magic to work on Ipython notebook.

Executing the following command

> %load_ext rpy2.ipython

results in an ['ImportError: No moduled named ipython'](http://pastebin.ca/2879304):

```
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
 <ipython-input-18-691c6d73b073> in <module>()
 ----> 1 get_ipython().magic(u'load_ext rpy2.ipython')
 
 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.pyc in magic(self, arg_s)
    2203         magic_name, _, magic_arg_s = arg_s.partition(' ')
    2204         magic_name = magic_name.lstrip(prefilter.ESC_MAGIC)
 -> 2205         return self.run_line_magic(magic_name, magic_arg_s)
    2206 
    2207     #-------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.pyc in run_line_magic(self, magic_name, line)
    2124                 kwargs['local_ns'] = sys._getframe(stack_depth).f_locals
    2125             with self.builtin_trap:
 -> 2126                 result = fn(*args,**kwargs)
    2127             return result
    2128 
 
 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/magics/extension.pyc in load_ext(self, module_str)
 
 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/magic.pyc in <lambda>(f, *a, **k)
     191     # but it's overkill for just that one bit of state.
     192     def magic_deco(arg):
 --> 193         call = lambda f, *a, **k: f(*a, **k)
     194 
     195         if callable(arg):
 
 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/magics/extension.pyc in load_ext(self, module_str)
      61         if not module_str:
      62             raise UsageError('Missing module name.')
 ---> 63         res = self.shell.extension_manager.load_extension(module_str)
      64 
      65         if res == 'already loaded':
 
 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/extensions.pyc in load_extension(self, module_str)
      96             if module_str not in sys.modules:
      97                 with prepended_to_syspath(self.ipython_extension_dir):
 ---> 98                     __import__(module_str)
      99             mod = sys.modules[module_str]
     100             if self._call_load_ipython_extension(mod):
 
 ImportError: No module named ipython
```

Any clue what it may be the problem?

Thanks

---

edit: June 1, 2016

Import statement was missing as well

> import rpy2.ipython
>
> %load_ext rpy2.ipython

Comment: Are you sure to have rpy2 2.5.2 installed ? This could happen is ipython is fetching an older version of rpy2.

Comment: Pretty sure, that's what it said when I ran help(rpy2). Will try again on Monday.

Comment: Thanks Igautier, you provided the solution here: [pip install singledispatch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27136523/rpy2-installation-error-os-linux-mint-17-r-3-1-2-python-2-7-6/27140070?noredirect=1#comment42876057_27140070)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

`$ conda install -c r r-essentials`

Then:

`$ conda install -c r rpy2`

*Consider install any dependency on this context with `conda` not with `pip`.*

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried typing the command `activate root` on the cmd window before starting the notebook ?

Comment: It works now. especially when managed by anaconda. Back in 2014, the repositories were not as established / frequently updated.